# How to continue execution from where the excel stopped?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

I am working with excel using selenium web driver where username and password is passed is taken from  excel and passed to application,pass/fail status is written back to excel.During exceptions such as no element found etc the execution stops. How to continue execution from the point where it stopped in the excel. Following is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException;

public class Checkbox2 {

        static WebDriver driver;
        private static  String filePath = "C:\\TEST DATA\\Users\\test.xlsx";
        private static String sheetName = "Sheet1";
        static File fl= new File(filePath);
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException
        {  
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Users\\vijayab\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.get("https://qa-bnymellon.correctnet.com/bnymellon/release10/me.get?DPS.home");

        //    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/a[1]")).click();

            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\vijayab\\Documents\\Work\\TEST DATA\\Users\\test.xlsx");
                Workbook wb;
                wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
               Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

                for(int count=0;count<=sheet.getLastRowNum();count++)
                {
                    Row row = sheet.getRow(count);
                    System.out.println("\n----------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Running test case " + count);

                    runTest(count, sheet, row.getCell(0).toString(),row.getCell(1).toString(),row,wb);

                }
                fis.close();
                driver.close();// Closing the firefox driver instance
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Test data file not found");
            }

        }

        public static  void runTest(int count,Sheet sheet,String name,String mailid, Row row, Workbook wb) throws InterruptedException, InvalidFormatException, IOException 
        {       
            System.out.println("Inputing name: "+name+" and mailid: "+mailid);
            driver.findElement(By.name("USERNAME")).sendKeys(name);
            driver.findElement(By.name("PASSWORD")).sendKeys(mailid);
            driver.findElement(By.name("SIGNIN")).click();
            //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          try{
              if(driver.findElements(By.name("loginForm")).size() == 0){
                    System.out.println("Valid credentials"+count);
                    driver.findElement(By.name("DISCLAIMER")).click();

                    driver.findElement(By.id("ACCOUNTDOCUMENTS")).click();

                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Account Profile')]")).click(); 
                  Thread.sleep(3000);

                   driver.switchTo().frame("FDX1");

                   driver.switchTo().frame("frame2-1");
                   Thread.sleep(4000);
                    driver.findElement(By.name("chk")).click();

                   driver.findElement(By.name("PROFILE_UPDATE")).click();
                    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
                    alert.accept();

                    driver.get("<logout url>");

                    int cellindex = 3;
                    WriteToFile.setExcelData(wb,filePath, sheetName, row.getRowNum(),cellindex, "PASS");
                    System.out.println("Inputted name: "+name+" and mailid: "+mailid);
                    Thread.sleep(2000); 
            }
              else if(driver.findElements(By.name("loginForm")).size() == 0){
                  driver.findElement(By.name("loginForm")).isDisplayed();

                    System.out.println("Inputted name: "+name+" and mailid: "+mailid + "does not exist");
                    int cellindex = 3;
                    WriteToFile.setExcelData(wb,filePath, sheetName, row.getRowNum(),cellindex, "Fail");
                    return;
              }
          }
          catch(UnreachableBrowserException e){
              System.out.println("Exception occured");

          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be different ways to handle it. What i would suggest is below one.

Add another `Catch` block to catch `Exceptions` in method `runTest`. Return a`Boolen`value as false in case of exceptions. Based on the return type, decide on how to proceed further in you `For Loop`. I Guess this should help you solve the problem. Please let me know in case of any queries.